# Python: Eval with undefined variables (2*x+x = 3*x)

Tags: python, variables, placeholder

I'm looking for a way, to calculate strings, that might include variables. `eval` won't do the job, as I want to use undefined variables. I'm talking about a function, that would turn `"2*3*x"` to `"6*x"` for example.

Is there a function for that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [sympy](http://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) for symbolic computation:

```
In [126]: import sympy as sy

In [127]: sy.simplify('2*x+x')
Out[127]: 3*x
```

To convert rationals to floats, use [`sy.nfloat`](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/core.html#nfloat):

```
In [170]: sy.nfloat(sy.simplify('2*3+x+3/4'))
Out[170]: x + 6.75
```

Comment: No it's not, sorry. I'm looking for something, that calculates numbers side by side with the variables. But as I type 2*3+x+3/4, it calculates different calculations seperated: x + 27/4. Is there a way, to fully solve those things?

Comment: What is the desired output for `2*3+x+3/4`? Please edit the Q to clarify what you want.

Comment: x+6.75 would it be. Is there a way to turn fractions  into floats inside a string?

Comment: That's it now. Thank you very much ^^ :)

Answer (score 0):

I maybe misunderstand your question completely but you said in your OP that: *I'm talking about a function, that would turn `2*3*x to 6*x`*
If this is what you need then it's very easy, just use parenthesis :

```
(2*3)*x
```

Comment: You understood the question displayed above. But it was changed by a mod. I just changed it back. I'm looking for a way, to do all that inside a string.

Comment: What do you mean by inside a string exactly?

Comment: "(2*3*x)" -> "6*x" without eval or exec.

Comment: You mean you want to print out the number inside a string?